# Coding a modal popup in PhP w/in a conditional statement

Tags: php, html, css, popup, modal-dialog

In reference to: yvesmancera post around April 21, 2013:

I too am looking for a way to make this auto-open, but with a twist.

I am working on a PhP shopping cart that only displays an error message in a very small red on black font (example-it varies), "Your credit card was declined (27): The transaction has been declined because of an AVS mismatch. The address provided does not match billing address of cardholder." just below the page header.

Having added all of the code from the Modal Pop-up example, the pop-up will not auto display.

Example here: [Creating a modal window with HTML5 & CSS3](http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2012/10/creating-a-modal-window-with-html5-and-css3/)

Essentially I have a PhP condition block to check the existence of an "error message" from the shopping cart program (3rd party).  My hope is to only pop-up the modal display box if/when there is a message to be shown.

Here is my "long way" around showing the "Click link":

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['error']))
{
$error=$_GET['error'];
if ($error==1)
{
?>
<p><a href="#openModal">Open Modal to see pop-over</a></p>
<?php
}
}
?>
```

I would like to have the modal pop-up show in the place of the href link.

Could someone help me with this?  I am fairly new, so detailed instructions are appreciated.

I had thought of a few ideas:

1) a div wrapper-container for the error message block (which is dynamically built)

```
<div id="ccError">
<div id="openModal" class="modalDialog">
<div>
<a href="#close" title="Close" class="close">X</a>
<h2>Credit Card Error!</h2>
<p>Your credit card was declined (27): The transaction has been declined because of an AVS mismatch. The address provided does not match billing address of cardholder.</p>
</div>  
</div>
</div>
```

2) I will need some combination of HTML/PhP/JS to make it work.

Comment: Did you want us to code that for you? Or did you want to Google for JavaScript modal windows?

Comment: Jay,   I would appreciate some assistance.   I have Googled for examples, but was not able to find any examples that would fit my goal.

Comment: What kind of assistance? If you want to write some code that attempts to fit your requirements we can help you to fix it.

Comment: Thank you Jay, I appreciate it.    I wrote some code and tried to find examples that did not require a "click event".   Would you be willing to provide some ideas?  I was wondering if a jQuery type of "fire" event would work - but had problems coding similar samples (unrelated to this).

Comment: jQuery does have a `.trigger()` which should work for you. http://api.jquery.com/trigger/

Comment: Looking @ the sample, I see it updates a counter based upon button clicks.  In my case, I need the page to "render" and when it finishes building the output, the modal pop-up will appear within the <html> table <tags>.   Right now the process "builds" the page and inserts the "CC Error" message within a series of <table><tr><td> with PhP used to process the "CC Error" message in a routine that extracts the message from the message object.   I am pretty new to all of this, hope I explained it correctly.

Comment: Then execute the modal on load, for instance: `$(window).load(function() { //pop up modal here });`

Comment: I looked at that event function and coded a sample, but it ended up just displaying the modal box and not the underlying rendered page.   We are using jquery-1.11.0.js as our framework.    --thanks for your help!

Comment: You have to put that code at the end of the originally rendered page.

Comment: OH!   If I understand correctly, the "final" thing that is within the <body> tag (following any other PhP includes, other JS) needs to be the jQuery to "fire" the event I am wanting done (ie: modal pop-up w/the message from the present code?)   Thus, I need to code the necessary modal "tags" in the HTML tags (up above), but reference them at the very end?

Comment: Jay I feel really stupid!  But I am still not getting it to work outside of a clickable "event" <a href="#openModal">click</a> . . . <div id="openModal" class="modalDialog"><div><a href="#close" title="Close" class="close">X</a>text - message to user</div></div>.

Comment: What code are you using to open the modal?

Comment: Jay...  thanks so much for your help, I just think I need to "go back to school" and buy, read, code/practice with some jQuery books (Sitepoint: jQuery Novice to Ninja & Learning jQuery 1.3" before I continue to utilize your skills.     I am always willing to learn from experts like you.

Comment: You're welcome, always glad to try and help. You may want to check out [Applied jQuery](http://www.amazon.com/Applied-jQuery-Develop-Jay-Blanchard/dp/0321772563) and [jQuery & jQuery UI Visual Quickstart](http://www.amazon.com/jQuery-UI-Visual-QuickStart-Guide/dp/0321885147/ref=la_B00TPXINV6_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1449669799&sr=1-1) ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯